# SQL Assign variable to function result within SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a SELECT statement that uses the result of a function multiple times.  Instead of repetitively tapping the function, is there a way that I can assign a variable to it in order to make the statement more efficient and I don't have to keep tapping the function?

Overly Simplified Hypothetical Example Code:

```
DECLARE @Total Decimal(18,2)

SELECT t.ClientName AS Customer, t.ClientID,
--This function returns total sales for the Client
@Total = dbo.functionSalesTotal(t.ClientID), 
@Total AS Sales, (@Total * 0.13) AS Tax, 
(@Total + (@Total *0.13)) AS TotalIncludingTax
FROM table t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery or `apply` is the best approach:

```
SELECT t.ClientName AS Customer, t.ClientID, 
       v.total AS Sales, (v.Total * 0.13) AS Tax, 
       (v.Total + (v.Total *0.13)) AS TotalIncludingTax
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (dbo.functionSalesTotal(t.ClientID)) as v(total);
```

Comment: Function may by deterministic